# How can I make a computed property compute itself in wish?

Tags: swift, swiftui

As far as I know if we are using a computed property we do not need to use `@Published` wrapper so if I make this code below and I don´t want use `@Published` and I want to have just computed property how can i make this property compute itself again?

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var test: Test = Test.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text(test.value)
            
            Button("update") {
                // need to force value to get itself again! How?
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
    }
}


class Test: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared: Test = Test()
    
    var value: String {
        return String(describing: Int.random(in: 1...1000))
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Make it a function

Comment: computed property

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why don't you want to use `@Published`? You could totally just have a `@Published var value = String(describing: Int.random(in: 1...1000))`, and have a function that recomputes `String(describing: Int.random(in: 1...1000))` and assign that to the property. You can then call that function in the button action.

Comment: I know all of that, the idea of using a computed property is for avoiding having stored value also in main time being automatic and no need to updating it.

Comment: Computed properties don’t have the ability to compute themselves, what you are look for is a “Publisher” of some kind.

Comment: I still haven't figured out what "in wish" means.

Comment: @matt: What language you understand better? I can try translate it for you in wish. 

Comment: I was hoping for English. Do you mean "on demand"? "On request"? "At will"?

Comment: Those are much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use a state variable to hold the value to display. Then you can update it in your button callback:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var test: Test = Test.shared
    @State private var val = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text(val)

            Button("update") {
                val = test.value
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
        .onAppear { val = test.value }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is almost like having a function and calling the function for new value, it was not exactly what I was looking but since this the only way I accept it, also you can remove onAppear and use this `@State private var val: String = Test.shared.value`